# JPA many to many relationship causing infinite recursion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Edit: I solved the problem using @JsonIgnoreProperties in both classes

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties("pokemons")
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "pokemon_types",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pokemon_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_id"))
private Set<Type> types;


@JsonIgnoreProperties("types")
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "types")
Set<Pokemon> pokemons;
```

I have two entities in my api. Pokemon which has a list of "types" that pokemon have and Type which has a list of "pokemon" that have that specific type. I'm trying to implement a getAll method in my controllers but i'm having an infinite recursion problem.

I've tried to use the @JsonIgnore annotation in my type class but with this i'm not able to get the list of pokemons inside each type. The other side of the relashionship works well.

Is there any way to avoid the infinite recursion problem and at the same time get both lists of the relashionship.

My repositories extend the JpaRepository and my controllers just call the findAll method of the JpaRepository.

Pokemon:

```
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="pokemons")
public class Pokemon implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String url;
    
    private String img;
    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "pokemon_types",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pokemon_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "type_id"))
    private Set<Type> types;
    
}
```

Type:

```
@Setter @Getter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="types")
public class Type implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "types")
    Set<Pokemon> pokemons;

}
```

Expected result:

```
[
   {
      id: ...,
      name: ...,
      pokemons: [
         {
            id: ...,
            name; ...
            url: ...
            img: ...
         },
         .
         .
         .
      ]
   },
   .
   .
   .
]
```

Actual result:

```
[
   {
      id: ...,
      name: ...,
   },
   .
   .
   .
]
```

Comment: Use `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
      property = "id")` on both class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `@JsonManagedReference` `@JsonBackReference` (latter to be used on the child entity) from the `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` package.

Also explained here: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion section 3

Comment: Thanks for the reply but with this aproach i have the same problem but with the other side of the relashionship (i.e. i'm not able to retrieve the list of types that each pokemon have)

Comment: @LeonardoRocha If you look at the example I linked, you can see that there is also an explanation to `@JsonIdentityInfo` which could be a solution for your problem

Comment: The `@JsonIdentifyInfo` didn't solve my problem but the article you posted lead me to another article in baeldung that solved.
I used `@JsonIgnoreProperties` in both attributes of the classes.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Removing getter of Id from type table will also work